# Laravel create FormRequest only for authorizarion

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

There is some endpoint like `users/{user_id}/events/`. It's available only with auth token -

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth:api'], function ()
```

But I need one more level of protection. This endpoint should be available only for the user which id is equal to `user_id`. I mean `users/1/events/` is available for the user with id 1.

I know two ways to solve it:

1. Create FormRequest and check all inside `authorize` method.
2. Check it inside the method in the Controller.

I prefer the first approach to have thin controllers. But have doubts, is it good to do it thus or there is a better solution?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to handle it inside controller, you can use FormRequest or Middleware. FormRequest is a good choice for you task.